# Joomla Login module not working in artcle

Tags: caching, authentication, module, joomla

I am loading the Joomla login module in an article using `{loadposition xxx}`.
when cache is on it doesn't works and give the error of Invalid Token.

What I figured out is that it is taking value of hidden field of the Joomla token from the cache which is usually generated randomly differently every time login module is loaded.

Can anybody have some idea to make it works?

Answer (score 0):

First you cannot remove the hidden field of the token because this way the form will never work ... It's a required parameter so you have to restore it back and follow these steps

- Go to the Module manager
- One the module
- The first item on the parameters is called "Caching" set it to **never**.

**EDIT**

You better use the plugin [Modules Anywhere](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/modulesanywhere) by Nonumber.nl

It fix 99$ of the issues that occur because of {loadposition} in regards to module title, content, caching ... etc

Comment: i tried it but it only disable that particular modules cache. But when a module is loaded in article using loadposition, it becomes a part of  article and here cache of com_content comes into action. whatever the cache settings of module, artice will always render from the cache of com_content.

Comment: Are you using the {loadposition} plugin to insert the module within the contents?